# npm WARN jest-react-native@17.0.0 requires a peer of whatwg-fetch@^1.0.0 but none was installed

Tags: android, reactjs, npm, react-native

When I try to run npm install in ReactNative project, I get this error.To solve this I try to install whatwg-fetch@^1.0.0 also but same error .

```
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY whatwg-fetch@2.0.1

npm WARN jest-react-native@17.0.0 requires a peer of whatwg-fetch@^1.0.0 but none was installed.
npm ERR! code 1
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to manually install missing peer dependencies
`npm install whatwg-fetch@^1.0.0 --save`

Comment: it works but i use :  npm install whatwg-fetch@^1.0  --save    Using npm install whatwg-fetch@^1.0.whatwg-fetch@^1.0.0 --save gives error

Comment: sorry about that, a copy paste error slipped into my answer

Comment: what does `--save` do? why `npm install whatwg-fetch@^1.0.0` doesn't fix the problem as I did that previously?